# How do I see source files in Safari?

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

[image: Chrome Source Files]

How do I get to this view in Safari? I don't see anything in Resources or Debugger tabs. Does Safari not support source script viewing?

Answer (score 1):

Choose "show page source" from the "Develop" menu.
If you don't have the "develop" menu, you can enable it like so:
Open Safari > Preferences, and click on the Advanced Tab:  Check "show develop menu in menu bar".
Resources and stylesheets etc. can be viewed on the bottom left.

Answer (score 0):

CMD + Shift + I

That's the developer tools shortcut